# One day every month or for a day in every month?

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage, expressions, meaning-in-context

I am an online seller at Amazon and I will put a note on my product. But how to create this sentence I am not 100% sure.

Ventilating one day every month will extend the life of the product.
or
Ventilating for a day in a month will extend the life of the product.

or how should I make this sentence in other way? I want to say that customers should ventilate the product one whole day in every month. Otherwise the product gets mold.

Comment: 'Ventilating [for a whole day] once a month will extend the life of the product.'

Comment: The description itself is unclear. What is being recommended? An uninterrupted period of ventilation of 24 hours once a month (and presumably at the *end* of each month), or intermittent ventilation at various times over the entire month that add up to 24 hours?

Comment: Hello Jason and Edwin thanks for your answers, yes it looks a bit unclear. I mean It should be ventilated at the end of each month. I thought that customers can understand that it would be ventilated every after 30 days not in the middle of the months. But you are right I couldn't make the sentence much clear. Jason how would you create this sentence after this information?